# Scrapyでコーディングしても"INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)"となりクローリングができない

Tags: python, web-scraping

wikipediaのサイトをscrapyでスクレイピングしたところ、うまくwebをクローリングしてくれません。
具体的には下記のメッセージが表示されているので情報をうまく取れていないと思います。

メッセージ一部抜粋

```
INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

下記にてspiderファイルとitemファイルを共有いたします。
考えられる修正点をご教示いただけますでしょうか。

クローリング先のサイトは下記です。

日本酒の銘柄一覧
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E9%85%92%E3%81%AE%E9%8A%98%E6%9F%84%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7

県名(prefecture)、酒造(syuzo)、日本酒名(sake_name)を取得したいと思っております。

scrapy_sake.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from sake.items import SakeItem

class ScrapySakeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapy_sake'
    allowed_domains = ['ja.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E9%85%92%E3%81%AE%E9%8A%98%E6%9F%84%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7']

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        レスポンスに対するパース処理
        """
        items = []
        for post in response.css('.mw-parser-ouput div ul li'):
            # items に定義した Post のオブジェクトを生成して次の処理へ渡す            
            item = SakeItem()
            item["prefecture"] = post.css('.mw-parser-ouput .mw-headline::text').extract()

            item["syuzo"] = post.css('.mw-parser-ouput div p b a::text').extract()
            if syuzo != None:
                    syuzo = syuzo
            else:
                syuzo=post.css('.mw-parser-ouput div p b::text').extract()
            item["sake_name"] = post.css('.mw-parser-ouput div ul li::text').extract()
            items.append(item)
            return items
```

item.py

```
import scrapy


class SakeItem(scrapy.Item):
    prefecture = scrapy.Field()
    syuzo = scrapy.Field()
    sake_name = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

「日本酒の銘柄一覧」のソースコード(HTML)を眺めてみましたが、あまり構造化されていません。とりあえずは必要なタグを全て抽出してインスタンス(SakeItem class)を作成します。

```
def parse(self, response):
  """
  レスポンスに対するパース処理
  """
  item, items = None, []
  for post in response.css('h3 .mw-headline, h3~div p, h3~p, ul, #脚注'):
    prefecture = post.css('span.mw-headline::text').get(default=False)
    maker = post.css('p ::text').getall()
    label = post.css('ul li ::text').getall()
    end = post.css('#脚注').get(default=False)

    if end and item is not None:
      items.append(item)
      break

    if prefecture:
      if item is not None:
        items.append(item)
      item = SakeItem({
        'prefecture': prefecture, 'syuzo': [], 'sake_name': []
      })
    elif len(maker) > 0:
      item['syuzo'] += [''.join(maker).strip()]
    elif len(label) > 0:
      item['sake_name'] += label

  return items
```

**出力結果**

```
[{'prefecture': '北海道',
  'sake_name': ['小樽の貴醸酒（おたるのきじょうしゅ）',
                '亀甲蔵大吟醸（きっこうぐらだいぎんじょう）',
                '寳川（たからがわ）',
                        :
  'syuzo': ['田中酒造（小樽市）',
            '男山（旭川市）',
            '高砂酒造（旭川市）',
                        :

 {'prefecture': '青森県',
  'sake_name': ['じょっぱり',
                '豊盃（ほうはい）',
                '霊峰（れいほう）',
                        :
  'syuzo': ['六花酒造（弘前市）',
            '三浦酒造店（弘前市）',
            '斎藤酒造（弘前市）',
                        :
```